# Who do I complain to if my data privacy has been violated in India?

Tags: india

I recently filled out the mandatory [Air Suvidha form](https://www.newdelhiairport.in/airsuvidha/apho-registration) before flying to India. A pdf of the form was then emailed out to me, but it didn't have the auto-generated registration number on it.

Shortly after submitting the form, I received emails from four other random people saying they had received my form instead of theirs. The form contains my date of birth, phone number, home address, passport number etc.

A few hours later I submitted the form again, and this time it seemed to work as intended and I got my own form with a registration number.

I have already complained to the grievance officer as per the [New Delhi Airport privacy policy](https://www.newdelhiairport.in/privacy-policy). I haven't had a response from them yet, but it's only been a day.

Is there anything else I can do in the meantime? Am I likely to get any compensation? Or, is this kind of stuff just common in India and accepted as normal?

If I were in the UK, I'd reach out to Citizen's advice. But, not sure what to do in India.

Comment: This may be more suitable for [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Sorry but what is your goal here? You can complain all day long , nothing will happen , at the very best you will get a canned apology letter most likely your complaint will be filed in the nearest wastebasket.